# Authenticate with the Dynamics CRM in Android

Tags: android, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

Is it possible to develop Android mobile applications that can connect to the Dynamics CRM organization web service and perform various operations (CRUD) without using OAuth authentication (Azure Active Directory Authentication Library) ?

Is it possible to authenticate with SOAP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible 
You can use SOAP Authentication
[SOAP Only Authentication](http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-java.html)

There is also a starter app ready to go 
[Connecting Android app to Dynamics CRM with SOAP endpoint](https://github.com/Scaleable-solutions/Connecting-Android-apps-to-Dynamics-CRM-using-SOAP-endpoint)